# Transferring my reps from dormant account

Tags: feature-request, reputation, merge-accounts, multiple-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

I have had two accounts on stackoverflow, while one being now the dormant one and the other one is active. I have gained some karma on the previous account and would like to know if it is possible to transfer my reps to the new account, that I am currently using. I know this sounds absurd but just thought to ask.

Comment: Why did you leave behind your old account? Why not simply change the name on it instead of starting a new one?

Comment: This should happen automatically if the two accounts get merged.